# Registration on Success Page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, register, password

I want to add the possibility to ask the guest customer to create an account on the success page in Magento2, after the order has been received in magento just like this.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Laura, As far as I know Magento by default provides create account options for guest user on checkout success page. Although it redirect user to create account page. you can check if it works for you.

Comment: I know but I need to add password field on success page instead of sending link in email to reset password. I have checked another post on stack overflow but its for Magento1 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243773/registration-on-success-page-in-magento2